# why doesnt this onclick jquery work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML

```
<input type="text" id="one" />
<input type="text" id="two" />

<button type="button" id="onebtn" >hide</button>
```

and js as

```
$('#onebtn').on('click',function(){
    $('#one').fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $('#two').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

but this doesn't seem to work but, if I use `<input type="button" />` it works, but I want to use `<button ></button>`

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fzg7b/

Comment: if you load jQuery, it works...

Comment: it works http://jsfiddle.net/Fzg7b/2/

Comment: Is this code siting inside the [document ready callback](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about forgetting to load jQuery.

Comment: Also, he is trying to fade in the second textbox...however it's already being shown. You can't fade in an item that's already displayed.

Comment: For the meta fans... [There is not enough jQuery in this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/172936).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to use `.click()`?

```
$('#onebtn').click(function(){
                                 $('#one').fadeOut('slow',function(){
                                 $('#two').fadeIn('slow');
                                    });
                                });
```

It may help, but I had no time to test this.

Comment: And this is the answer!! This worked well..and i forgot to load the jquery in the fiddle.It did worked.But where I was testing this didnt worked with the jquery I provided.But this one worked.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @BlackSheep No one could tell it

Comment: @user3150930 It only makes a difference if you are using jQuery 1.6- which doesn't support the `on` method.

Comment: @BlackSheep whatever it worked well for me anyways..

Answer (score 5):

It is because, you are not loading jQuery in your fiddle.

Load the jQuery version from the top left side. Then it would work!

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/Fzg7b/5/

Try it here! It is working.

And for information as C Fairweather has mentioned to use

```
$(function(){ 
   /* A shortcut for dom ready */
});
```

No jQuery code would work if there is no DOM ready function what we see as

```
$(document).ready(fucntion () {
   /* functions here.. */
})
```

But jsfiddle doesn't need this! So it is not required! But a good point to come up with. :)

Comment: This is correct. Also, it's recommended that you attach events after dom ready. `$(function(){ /* A shortcut for dom ready */});`

Answer (score 0):

also, you are displaying both the textbox1 and textbox2 elements. Then saying fade the first out and fade the second in but the second textbox is already visible. You cannot fade in an already visible item. Set the second textbox to hidden.

```
<input type="text" id="two" style="display: none;" />
```

Once this is done, your code functions as expected. Also, in your jsfiddle...remember to select the jquery version you are using. Currently you load nothing.